# Make NPC Look Like a Player in ROBLOX

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I am trying to make a NPC look like a player for a title screen.

I don't need a tutorial on how to make an NPC; I know how to make an NPC look like someone. Instead, I need to know how to clone the exact appearance of a player within a script. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a given player's character model can be found at a [`Player`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/class/Player)'s [`.Character`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/property/Player/Character) attribute. The `.Character` attribute is a [`Model`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/class/Model), which, along with most other kinds of objects in the game, has a [`:Clone()`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/function/Instance/Clone) function. You can use this function to make a complete copy of the player's character model. For example:

```
player = path.to.player.here

copy = player.Character:Clone()
copy.Parent = game.Workspace --put the clone into the physical environment
```

However, **there is a catch if you are using this for a title screen** like you said: when a player joins the game, **their character will not load immediately**; instead, it will take a few seconds. You can probably see this for yourself if you trying playing a game and then pay attention to how long it takes before you are actually placed into your character. Because of this, if you try to use `.Character` right when someone joins your game, **your code will break**. To account for this, you can use a special features of ROBLOX called `Event`s.

ROBLOX has special objects called [`Event`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/datatype/RBXScriptSignal)s. `Event`s have a special `:connect()` function, which allows you to connect functions to those events. When you connect a function to an `Event`, that function will be executed when the `Event` occurs.

In your case, you will need **two** `Events`:

1. one for when a `Player` joins the game
2. one for when their physical `.Character` `model` has actually loaded

First of all, let's talk about when a `Player` joins the game. First, we need to get the [`Players`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/class/Players) object—an object that keeps track of information about all of the players. We will use a special function of `game` called [`:GetService()`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/function/ServiceProvider/GetService):

```
players = game:GetService("Players")
```

Now, we will use a special `Event` in `Players` called [`.PlayerAdded`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/event/Players/PlayerAdded):

```
players = game:GetService("Players")

players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)

end)
```

Notice that the `Player` that was actually added will be passed as an argument to the parameter `player`. Now, we will use a special `Event` of `Player`s called [`CharacterAdded`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/event/Player/CharacterAdded):

```
players = game:GetService("Players")

players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:connect(function(character)

    end
end)
```

Notice that the `Character` of the `Player` will be conveniently passed as an argument to the parameter `character`, so we don't even need to use `Player.Character`. Now, we can take our cloning code from earlier and finally put it inside this code:

```
players = game:GetService("Players")

players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:connect(function(character)
        local copy = character:Clone()
        copy.Parent = game.Workspace --put the clone into the physical environment

        --your code here
    end
end)
```

And that's it! Now you can put all of your code that deals with the clone in place of `--your code here`.

One final note is that this needs to be done in a regular [`Script`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/class/Script), ***not*** a [`LocalScript`](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference/class/LocalScript). `Script`s are handled by the ROBLOX server, whereas `LocalScript`s are handled by the players' computers themselves. Because the server handles players being added to a game, you must use a `Script`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to assume that you're trying to make a NPC looking like a player? This can take a bit of work, but you have to find the player in the `game.Workspace` that you want the NPC to look like, then you can either clone the player and insert the npc's parts into it, or you can just insert the cloned player into the npc.

As far as I see it, there isn't a way to do this without doing it within a script.